# How to use valgrind to detect memory leak of customized alloc/free?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

In my app, I created a customized my_alloc/my_free, and want to detect memory leak of the customized memory management using valgrind(or other tools)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind has an API that you can use to describe your "memory pool management".

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools
for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, rather than using your own function names, you could simply use 'malloc', 'free' etc.

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html) is a link on what needs to be done when using GCC. Depending on how you link your replacement malloc functions you may need to use the `--soname-synonyms` parameter (towards the end of [this section](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.rareopts) of the Valgrind manual).